# Merging rectangles in C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I have the following code for separating out overlapping rectangles vs.
non-overlapping rectangles in C++ 11:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv/cxcore.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <array>

int main() {
    auto detected = get_detected();
    std::vector <Rect> singles;
    std::vector <Rect> overlaps;
    for (auto rect_1: detected) {
        bool isSingle = false;
        for (auto rect_2: detected) {
            if (rect_1 == rect_2) {
                continue;
            }
            bool intersects = ((rect_1 & rect_2).area() > 0);
            if (intersects) {
                isSingle = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isSingle) {
            singles.push_back(rect_1);
        } else {
            overlaps.push_back(rect_1);
        }
    }

}
```

How do I make this cleaner? I'm thinking of doing `singles.push_back(std::move(rect_1));`, but I'm not sure if that's a good idea.

I would love some guidance in the right direction.

Comment: Where is `get_detected()` defined?

Comment: This looks like it has a bug, you never set `isSingle` to true.

Comment: If you have many rectangles then you probably want to use a data structure that is dedicated to your problem instead of lists. See for example [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39131196/data-structure-for-determining-intersection-of-rectangle-with-a-larger-set-of-re).

Comment: You can get rid of the loop spaghetti introduced by the usage of `break` and `continue` with an iterator-based outer loop and replacing the inner loop with `std::find_if(i, end(), predicate)`. I had a nice spelled answer but unfortunately this question get closed before I could post. **That** would be clean code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Bug

```
        if (intersects) {
            isSingle = false;
            break;
        }
```

This looks like a bug. The variable `isSingle` is already false. Setting it to false here does nothing.

### Code Review:

You use `std::vector` but don't include its header.

```
    std::vector <Rect> overlaps;
```

You should fix that.

---

References and Const correctness.

This is a big part of C++.

1. If you are not modifying an object, prefer to use reference than making a copy of an object.
2. Prefer const references over normal references to prevent accidental modification.

   for (auto rect_1: detected) {

Here you are making a copy of the object from the array detected into the object `rect_1`. Personally I would use a const reference to prevent the overhead of a copy:

```
for (auto const& rect_1: detected) {
```

---

The code looks mostly fine:

I think the only bug is here:

```
            if (rect_1 == rect_2) {
                continue;
            }
```

This tells you if two rectangles are equivalent not if they are the same rectangle. If you have two distinct but otherwise identical rectangle then by my logic they would overlap and thus not be in the single's list.

So you need a way to determine if these are the same object. Personally I would do that by changing your `for` loops to use references and then comparing the objects' addresses.

```
    for (auto const& rect_1: detected) {
              ^^^^^^
        ...
        for (auto const& rect_2: detected) {
                  ^^^^^^
            if ( & rect_1 ==  & rect_2) {
                ^^^          ^^^
                continue;
            }

            test(rect_1, rect_2);
```

Your other alternative is to make sure you never compare an object with itself. This also brings into mind that you do twice as many comparisons as you need to. You compare every rectangle against every other rectangle. But if `A & B` overlap then we already know that `B & A` will overlap.

```
for(std::size_t loop = 0l; loop <  detected.size(); ++loop) {
    for(auto check = loop + 1; check < detected.size(); ++check) {
        test(detected[loop], detected[check]);
```

---

> in the code below "...object addresses" -- aren't `rect_1` and `rect_2` references already? If so, why can't we just do `if (rect_1 == rect_2)`

No. Because the `==` is supposed to compare the equality (is the state the same) of two objects. It is not supposed to be a test of equivalence (is it the same object).

Note: You can declare `operator==` to test if the objects are the same but that would be terrible practice and would cause a lot of issues with people expecting the normal operation. So don't do that. The above statement is said assuming you are following the normal idioms of the language.

I assume you are coming from a Java like background. The term *reference* in C++ has a different meaning than in Java. A reference means another name for an object (they are not like Java references (which in C++ we would call *pointers*). So a reference is another name for an object but the test `operator==` will compare if the two objects' state are the same (not if they are the same object).

> Also, if I use `auto const&`, I would have to change my return type to `vector<Rect&>`...is that idiomatic? I think the OpenCV API expects `vector<Rect>`

No. You can pass a reference to the vector and it will copy the object into the vector. You don't want to hold references in a vector.

Comment: in the code below "...object addresses" -- aren't `rect_1 `and `rect_2` references already?  If so, why can't we just do `if (rect_1 == rect_2)`?

Comment: Also, if I use `auto const&`, I would have to change my return type to `vector<Rect&>`...is that idiomatic? I think the opencv api expects vector<Rect>

Comment: @nz_21 Added some state to the question. As those comments are hard to answer in a comment.

Comment: This answer is nice but doesn’t fix the glaring bug in the code. It’s just rearranging the deck chairs, as it were. (I’m also not a big fan of the suggestion to use index-based loops over iterators.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph which bug did i not suggest a fix for?

Comment: It will never find single rectangles, since `isSingle` is never set to `true`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph lol. Yes. That is so true.

Answer (score 6):

Prefer `<cstdio>` to `<stdio.h>` and `<cmath>` to `<math.h>` in C++ code.  You will probably never need the C compatibility headers unless you're writing headers that must also be included in C code.  The compatibility headers are less useful in C++ code, because they declare everything in the global namespace rather than neatly in `std`.

Prefer not including headers at all when you don't use them (as is the case here).  Unnecessary includes waste the compiler's time and the reader's brainpower.